# Is there an alternate way to add default value to hashset and not disturb the HashSet Count?

Tags: c#

I want to know is there an alternative way to initialize HashSet with Default Value? For instance,

```
int[] array=new int[10];
/*This will initialize all array elements with zero*/-Value Type
HashSet<int>[] HSet= new HashSet<int>[10];
/*This will initialize all elements with Null Value*/-Reference Type
```

Now Lets assume i do some operation on HSet,may be HSet[i].ToString(),This would lead to NullReferenceException.To avoid this I would do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    HSet[i] =new HashSet<int>(){0};
}
```

But this will add element to set and increase the set count to one.
My question is,Is there an alternate way to add default value to hashset and not disturbing the HashSet Count?.i.e the hashset has to be initialized and count must be zero(Ideally no elements in Set)

I tried Initialize method that is provided with HashSet,no luck.

Comment: HSet.ToString() will not lead to NullReferenceException, since you have instance of HSet.  Do you mean HSet[x].ToString()?

Comment: @VladBezden:Yes i mean Hset[x].ToString().I have made an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a hash set with one item in it and count equal to zero. Hope, that makes sense.

Either create an empty set (`new HashSet<int>()`), or choose a useful default initial element and live with the count being one, or write your own set class (possibly wrapping a `HashSet`).

As the question stands you are asking for something impossible and it smells like the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with this. `new HashSet<int>(){0};` is syntactic sugar for initializing the HashSet and adding 0 to the set.  If you don't want any items in the set then omit the `{0}`.

Comment: @Parker do you think this is the misunderstanding? I'm really unclear on the thinking behind the question.

Comment: @usr:Can i have my hashset initialized(Not Null) and have my count of hashset to zero?

Comment: @restless I see. You don't understand the difference between reference types and value types. Make sure to nail your understanding of that perfectly. You'll be surprised all the time without this understanding. Learn about it and leave a comment here if you still cannot solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is,Is there an alternate way to add default value to
>   hashset and not disturbing the HashSet Count?

You can't

As soon as you call

```
var HSet = new HashSet<int>[10];
```

You created HashSet with 10 elements in it, doesn't matter if you set them or not.

> But this will add element to set and increase the set count to one

No, you already have your HashSet with 10 elements, so setting them to default value will not change Count

What you might consider instead of using array of HashSet to use List of HashSet List>, list is dynamic, so when you instantiate your list

```
var HSet = new List<HashSet<int>>();
```

you will have HSet.Count() equal 0.

> Can i have my hashset initialized(Not Null) and have my count of hashset to zero?

Yes, use:

```
var HSet = new List<HashSet<int>>();
```